# php script working every friday

Tags: php, date, hour

I have this script that is working every day between 2 hours. Now, I have 2 questions:
1) how do I make it work only every friday, not all days?
2) how do I use minutes to m code? $hour:$min > 8:15 is not working

```
<?php
$hour = date('G'); 
if ($hour >= 8 && $hour <= 10) { 
  include('facut_mine2.php');

 } 
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if nobody at that time visits the site?

Comment: :)) it is a site for pregnant mothers and every friday for two hours they gather to chat about their husbands. So I need to include a chat at that time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `date('w')` to get weekday

```
<?php
$start = strtotime('8:15');
$end = strtotime('9:45');

if(date('w') == 5){ // day 5 = Friday
    $timenow = date('U'); 
    if ($timenow >= $start && $timenow <= $end) { 
      include('facut_mine2.php');
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks man. now it is working! what is the difference between date('U') and date('G') ?

Comment: `U` return timestamp, `G` returns 24 hour format, [read here](http://uk.php.net/date)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$hour = date('G');
$day = date('w');
if ($day == 5 && $hour >= 8 && $hour <= 10) { 
  include('facut_mine2.php');

 } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

by using D parameter in date() function you can retrieve the current week day:

```
$today = date('D');// $today = 'Wed'
```

and for minute you can again use date() function with i

```
 $current_min = date('i');

if(date('D') == 'Fri') { 
    $hourMin = date('H:i');
    if ($hourMin >= '08:15' && $hourMin <= '10:00') { 
      include('facut_mine2.php');
    } 
}
```